# Is it possible to display the contents of a div in extjs panel?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

I have some pre-existing js code that manipulates a `div` via DOM. I have a `Ext.container.Viewport` with a border layout. I want to display the contents of the `div` within a panel in the center region of the viewport.

**HTML**

```
<div id="contents"></div>
```

**EXTJS**

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
  layout: 'border',
  items: [{
    region: 'north',
    ...
  }, {
    region: 'center',
    items: [{          
        // #contents;
    }]
  ]}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in the [`contentEl`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-contentEl) configuration option. From the documentation:

> Specify an existing HTML element, or the id of an existing HTML element to use as the content for this component.
>
> This config option is used to take an existing HTML element and place it in the layout element of a new component (it simply moves the specified DOM element after the Component is rendered to use as the content.

There are some additional notes in the documentation, but it sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: looks to be working; this doesn't sound too good: _"The specified HTML element used will not participate in any layout scheme that the Component may use. It is just HTML. Layouts operate on child items."_ But, from my limited testing, it looks like the `border` layout is taking effect.

Comment: @wulfgar.pro, yes, that note is saying that it wont get sized by the parent, it will take the whole width but not the height, like regular divs

Answer (score 0):

NT3RP is correct, **contentEl** is what you need. Here is a code snippet:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout : {
                type : 'border'
            },
            items : [ {
                region : 'north',
                contentEl : 'header',   //content read from html div#header
                id : 'mainHeader'
            },
```

By the way default xtype for any reagion in the viewport is a Panel - so you don't have to create a new Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the `html` property of Ext.panel.Panel.

This has some slight differences to contentEl which are described in the API, but performs a similar task.

Comment: I tried assigning the DOM component to the html config - this did not work as expected.